# HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes /dd issue

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am having an issue selecting a  node in C# using HtmlAgilityPack, I usually select via class or name but it is not available in this case, but a different parameter is but I am unsure on how to select the object in C#.

HTML -  `<dd data-product-upc="">4895228608161</dd>`

C# - `figureItem.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd[@class='data-product-upc']");`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `figureItem.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd[@'data-product-upc']"` The data attribute obviously is not a class

Comment: Thank you, your answer is nearly correct just a small syntax error figureItem.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd[@'data-product-upc']"

Comment: @DeanBeckerton That's what you get for writing code on a smartphone :>